# Displaying relevant content

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, browser-detection

I want to display the correct script and hide the false script of this code depending on what device the end user is using.

```
    <ul class="pageitem">
<li class="button iphone"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='appiphone.html' " type="submit" /></li>
<li class="button ipad"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='appipad.html' " type="submit" /></li>
<li class="button android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='appandroid.html' " type="submit" /></li>
</ul>
```

Now I have this code that redirects the device to a specific page which I do not want any more.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width>801)
{
window.location="http://www.xclo.co.uk/PC.html"
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
        document.location = "android.html";
    } // ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var iphone = ((window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone'))||(window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPod')))?true:false;
var ipad = (window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPad'))?true:false;
if(iphone){
 document.location = 'iphone.html';
}
if(ipad){
 document.location = 'ipad.html';
}
</script>
```

Please can someone help me in getting this script to display the relevant content and not redirect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul class="pageitem">
    <li class="button iphone" id="iphone"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='appiphone.html';" type="submit" /></li>

    <li class="button ipad" id="ipad"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='appipad.html';" type="submit" /></li>

    <li class="button android" id="android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='appandroid.html';" type="submit" /></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mayShowElement(id, shouldShow)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = shouldShow ? 'block' : 'none';
    }

    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var MOBILE = {
        IS_IPHONE : userAgent.match('iPhone') || userAgent.match('iPod'),
        IS_IPAD   : userAgent.match('iPad'),
        IS_IPHONE : userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1
    };

    mayShowElement('iphone', MOBILE.IS_IPHONE);
    mayShowElement('ipad', MOBILE.IS_IPAD);
    mayShowElement('android', MOBILE.IS_ANDROID);
</script>
```

This seems to me to be a good solution (untested) based on your code.